# Access violation executing assembly function

Tags: assembly, x86-64, masm, visual-c++-2019

The assembly code:

```
_CODE SEGMENT
PUBLIC my_add_asm_call
my_add_asm_call PROC
    mov eax, 2 // the exception happens here.
    mov ecx, 3
    add eax, ecx
    ret
my_add_asm_call ENDP
_CODE ENDS
END
```

The C++ code:

```
extern "C" int my_add_asm_call();

int main()
{
    std::cout << my_add_asm_call();
}
```

I have not the slightest clue why this is happening, since using the x86_64 "rax" and "rcx" doesn't fix it. I don't really know assembly, as you may guess, but I would like to learn at least a little.

Comment: My guess is the `_CODE SEGMENT` doesn't actually define an executable segment. Try `_CODE SEGMENT 'code'` or just use `.code`.

Comment: The fault happens on a `mov`-immediate which doesn't access memory except for code-fetch.  Jester's suggestion of a your instructions being in a non-executable page sounds most likely.

Comment: @Jester Your solution works. :)